# $a+b+c+d+e=79$ with constraints

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

How many non-negative integer solutions are there to $a+b+c+d+e=79$ with the constraints $a\ge7$, $b\le34$ and $3\le c\le41$?

I get that for $a\ge7$ you do $79-7=72$, $\binom{72+5-1}{5-1}=\binom{76}4$. For $b\ge35$ I think it's $\binom{47}4$ and I'm not too sure what it is for $3\le c\le41$ and I also have no clue as to how to do them all at the same time.

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you solve it without the constraints using stars and bars?  For the $a \ge 7$ constraint, just make $a'=a-7$ and use that with a sum of $72$.  The rest?

Comment: Is the sum equal to $79$ or $75$?  Your attempt seems to be based on the latter number.

Comment: If you have a maximum, count the ways without the constraint and subtract the ways over the maximum.  You know how to do that from the $a$ constraint.  For $3 \le c \le 41$, let $c'=c-3$ to get the minimum, then subtract $c' \gt 38$ to get the maximum.

Comment: You need to consider all the constraints together, but your attempts only address one at a time; this is not sufficient.

Comment: Use Partition Theory.

Comment: Did you cover generating functions in class?

Answer (score 7):

> Here is an answer based upon *[generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function)*.
>
> - $a\geq 7$ can be encoded as
>     \begin{align*}
>   z^7+z^8+z^9+\cdots=z^7\left(1+z+z^2+\cdots\right)=\frac{z^7}{1-z}\tag{1}
>   \end{align*}
> - $b\leq 34$ can be encoded as
>     \begin{align*}
>   1+z+z^2+\cdots+z^{34}=\frac{1-z^{35}}{1-z}\tag{2}
>   \end{align*}
> - $3\leq c\leq 41$ can be encoded as
>     \begin{align*}
>   z^3+z^4+\cdots+z^{41}=z^3\left(1+z+z^2+\cdots+z^{38}\right)=\frac{z^3\left(1-z^{39}\right)}{1-z}\tag{3}
>   \end{align*}
> - $d,e\geq 0$ can be both encoded as
>     \begin{align*}
>   1+z+z^2+\cdots=\frac{1}{1-z}\tag{4}
>   \end{align*}

We want to find the number of non-negative integer solutions of
\begin{align*}
a+b+c+d+e=79
\end{align*}
with the constraints given above.

> Denoting with $[z^n]$ the coefficient of $z^n$ we are looking for 
>   \begin{align*}
> [z^{79}]&\frac{z^7}{1-z}\cdot\frac{1-z^{35}}{1-z}\cdot \frac{z^3\left(1-z^{39}\right)}{1-z}\cdot \left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^2\tag{5}\\
> &=[z^{79}]z^{10}\frac{(1-z^{35})(1-z^{39})}{(1-z)^5}\\
> &=[z^{69}]\frac{(1-z^{35})(1-z^{39})}{(1-z)^5}\tag{6}\\
> &=[z^{69}]\left(1-z^{35}-z^{39}\right)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-5}{k}(-z)^k\tag{7}\\
> &=\left([z^{69}]-[z^{34}]-[z^{30}]\right)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{k+4}{4}z^k\tag{8}\\
> &=\binom{73}{4}-\binom{38}{4}-\binom{34}{4}\tag{9}\\
> &=1088430-73815-46376\\
> &=968239
> \end{align*}
>
> in accordance with the answer of @CYKwong.

*Comment:*

- In (5) we select the coefficient of $[z^{79}]$ of the product of the generating functions (1) to (4) which correspond to the valid ranges specified for $a$ to $e$.
- In (6) we apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (7) we multiply out the numerator and skip terms with powers greater than $69$ since they do not contribute to $[z^{69}]$. We also apply the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.
- In (8) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator, apply the same rule as in (6) three times and use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{p-1}(-1)^q$.
- In (9) we select the coefficients accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$\sum_{m=k}^{n}\binom{m}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}$$

The number of solutions of the equation $d+e=79-a-b-c$ is

$$\begin{cases}\displaystyle \binom{79-a-b-c+1}{1}=\binom{80-a-b-c}{1}, &\text{if }a\le79-b-c \\[0.2cm] 0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$

The number of solutions of the equation $a+d+e=79-b-c$ such that $a\ge7$ is

$$\begin{cases} \displaystyle\sum_{a=7}^{79-b-c}\binom{80-a-b-c}{1}=\displaystyle\sum_{m=1}^{73-b-c}\binom{m}{1}=\binom{74-b-c}{2}, &\text{if }b\le 72-c \\[0.2cm] 0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$

The number of solutions of the equation $a+b+d+e=79-c$ such that $a\ge7$ and $b\le34$ is

\begin{align*}
&\;\begin{cases} \displaystyle\sum_{b=0}^{72-c}\binom{74-b-c}{2}=\sum_{m=2}^{74-c}\binom{m}{2}=\binom{75-c}{3}, &\text{if }39\le c\le 41 \\[0.2cm]\displaystyle\sum_{b=0}^{34}\binom{74-b-c}{2}=\sum_{m=40-c}^{74-c}\binom{m}{2}, &\text{if }c\le 38 \\[0.2cm] 0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases} \\
=&\;\begin{cases} \displaystyle\binom{75-c}{3}, &\text{if }39\le c\le 41 \\[0.2cm] \displaystyle \sum_{m=2}^{74-c}\binom{m}{2}-\sum_{m=2}^{39-c}\binom{m}{2} =\binom{75-c}{3}-\binom{40-c}{3}, &\text{if }c\le 37\\[0.2cm] 
\displaystyle \sum_{m=2}^{36}\binom{m}{2}=\binom{37}{3}, &\text{if }c= 38 \\[0.2cm] 0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}
\end{align*}

The number of solutions of the equation $a+b+c+d+e=79$ such that $a\ge7$ and $b\le34$ and $3\le x\le41$ is

\begin{align*}
&\;\sum_{c=3}^{37}\left[\binom{75-c}{3}-\binom{40-c}{3}\right]+\binom{37}{3}+\sum_{c=39}^{41}\binom{75-c}{3}\\
=&\;\sum_{m=38}^{72}\binom{m}{3}-\sum_{m=3}^{37}\binom{m}{3}+\binom{37}{3}+\binom{36}{3}+\binom{35}{3}+\binom{34}{3}\\
=&\;\sum_{m=3}^{72}\binom{m}{3}-2\sum_{m=3}^{37}\binom{m}{3}+\binom{37}{3}+\binom{36}{3}+\binom{35}{3}+\binom{34}{3}\\
=&\;\binom{73}{4}-2\binom{38}{4}+\binom{37}{3}+\binom{36}{3}+\binom{35}{3}+\binom{34}{3}\\
=&\;968239
\end{align*}

Comment: I checked the answer with an Excel VBA program. So I think it is correct.

Comment: The answer is also equal to $\displaystyle \binom{73}{4}- \binom{38}{4}- \binom{34}{4}$. Maybe there is a better method to reach the answer.

Comment: What about generating functions?

Comment: $\binom{73}{4}=\binom{79-7-3+5-1}{5-1}$ is the number of solutions with the constraints $a\ge7$ and $c\ge 3$.

Comment: @CYKwong: Nice answer. The results coincide. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

So we are looking for non-negative solutions for to $a+b+c+d+e=79$ with the constraints $a\ge7$, $b\le34$ and $3\le c\le41$

I always like, in this kind of problem, to work with generating functions. Everything variable gets a polynomial such that its powers correspond to the restraints, and such that he requested solution would be the coefficient of $x^{79}$ in their product:

The restriction on $a$ translates to the function $$(x^7 + x^8 + x^9 + \ldots) = x^7\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)$$ For $b$ we have $$(1+ x + x^2 + \ldots x^{34}) = \frac{1-x^{35}}{1-x}$$ all using standard geometric series. For $c$ we have $$\left(x^3 + x^4 + \ldots + x^{41}\right) = x^3\left(1+x+ \ldots + x^{38}\right) = x^3\left(\frac{1-x^{39}}{1-x}\right)$$ while $d$ and $e$ have no restrictions so we use $$(1+x+x^2 + \ldots) = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

So the answer to your question is the coefficient of $x^{79}$ in:

$$x^7 \frac{1}{1-x} (1-x^{35})\frac{1}{1-x} x^3 (1-x^{39})\frac{1}{1-x}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)^2 $$ which comes down to the coefficient of $x^{69}$ (removing the always present $x^{10}$) in:

$$(1-x^{35})(1-x^{39})(1-x)^{-5} = (1 - x^{35} - x^{39} + x^{74})\sum_{k=0}^\infty {k+4 \choose k} x^k$$ using the generalised binomial formula.

And this coefficient equals $${73 \choose 69} - {38 \choose 34}- {34 \choose 30}$$

Answer (score 0):

We may solve this problem by finding the number of solutions with the following constraints

(1) $a\ge7 $ and $c\ge3$

(2) $a\ge7 $ and $c\ge42$

(3) $a\ge7 $, $b\ge35$ and $c\ge3$

(4) $a\ge7 $, $b\ge35$ and $c\ge42$

The answer to the problem is the answer of (1) - the answer of (2) - the answer of (3) + the answer of (4)

(1) Let $a'=a-7$ and $c'=c-3$. The equation is equivalent to $a'+b+c'+d+e=79-7-3 $, where the variables are nonnegative integers. The number of solutions is $\binom{79-7-3+4} {4 }=\binom {73}{4}$.

(2) Similar to (1), the number of solutions is $\binom{79-7-42+4} {4 }=\binom {34}{4}$.

(3) The number of solutions is $\binom{79-7-3-35+4} {4 }=\binom {38}{4}$.

(4) is impossible as $a+b+c>79$.

Comment: how did you write case (2)$c \geq 42$ ,In the question the condition is $3 \leq c \leq 41 $!

Comment: It's inclusion - exclusion principle

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved using the principle of inclusion. First observe that the problem is equivalent to finding the number of non-negative integer solutions to 
$$
a'+b+c'+d+e=69\tag{1}
$$
where $b\leq 34, c'\leq 38$. Let $B$ be the set of non-negative integer solutions to (1) where $b\geq 35$ and $C$ be the set of set of non-negative integer solutions to (1) where $c'\geq 39$ and let $U$ be the set of non-negative integer solutions to (1) without any constraints. The number of solutions equals
$$
\begin{align}
|\bar{B}\cap\bar{C}|
&=|U|-|B|-|C|+|B\cap C|\\
&=\binom{5+69-1}{4}-\binom{5+(69-35)-1}{4}-\binom{5+(69-39)-1}{4} + 0\\
&=\binom{73}{4}-\binom{38}{4}-\binom{34}{4}
\end{align}
$$ 
by the principle of inclusion exclusion where $|B\cap C|=0$ since if $b\geq 35$ and $c'\geq 39$, then $b+c'\gt 69$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> How many non-negative integer solutions are there to
>   $\ds{a + b + c + d + e = 79}$ with the constraints
>   $\ds{\quad a \geq 7\,,\quad b \leq 34\quad\mbox{and}\quad
> 3 \leq c \leq 41}$ ?.

The answer is given by
\begin{align}
\mc{N} & =
\sum_{a = 7}^{\infty}\sum_{b = 0}^{34}\sum_{c = 3}^{41}\sum_{d = 0}^{\infty}
\sum_{e = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{z^{79}}z^{a + b + c + d + e} =
\sum_{a = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{b = 0}^{34}\sum_{c = 0}^{38}\sum_{d = 0}^{\infty}
\sum_{e = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{z^{79}}z^{\pars{a + 7} + b + \pars{c + 3} + d + e}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{69}}\sum_{a = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{b = 0}^{34}\sum_{c = 0}^{38}
\sum_{d = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{e = 0}^{\infty}z^{a + b + c + d + e} =
\bracks{z^{69}}\pars{\sum_{a = 0}^{\infty}z^{a}}^{3}
\pars{\sum_{b = 0}^{34}z^{b}}\pars{\sum_{c = 0}^{38}z^{c}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{69}}{1 \over \pars{1 - z}^{3}}\,{z^{35} - 1 \over z - 1}
\,{z^{39} - 1 \over z - 1} =
\bracks{z^{69}}{z^{74} - z^{39} - z^{35} + 1 \over \pars{1 - z}^{5}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\bracks{z^{30}}\pars{1 - z}^{-5} - \bracks{z^{34}}\pars{1 - z}^{-5} +
\bracks{z^{69}}\pars{1 - z}^{-5}
\\[5mm] & =
-{-5 \choose 30}\pars{-1}^{30} - {-5 \choose 34}\pars{-1}^{34} +
{-5 \choose 69}\pars{-1}^{69} =
-{34 \choose 30} - {38 \choose 34} + {73 \choose 69}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{968239}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$a+b+c+d+e=79$ over non-negative integers,
$a>=7,\;\;b<=34,\;\; 3<=c<=41$

Put $a'=a-7,\quad c'=c-3,\;$ then we have

$a'+b+c'+d+e = 69,\;\;b<34,\;\; c'<=38$, giving the answer of

$\dbinom{73}4 - \dbinom{38}4 - \dbinom{34}4$